# SELECT statement in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, sql-server-2005, select, jtable

```
    public void search() throws Exception{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                String url = "jdbc:odbc:******";
                String user = "*****";
                String pass = "*****";
                Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                Statement state = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("");
                ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
                int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
                DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
                Vector column_name = new Vector();
                Vector data_rows = new Vector();

                for (int i=1; i<columns;i++){
                    column_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
                }
                dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(column_name);

                while(rs.next()){
                    data_rows = new Vector();
                    for (int j=1; j<columns; j++){
                    data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
                    }
                    dtm.addRow(data_rows);
                }
                tblPatient.setModel(dtm);
        }
```

On my `ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery()` I used this `SQL`

```
                              "SELECT "
                            + "pIDNo AS 'Patient ID',"
                            + "pLName AS 'Last Name'," 
                            + "pFName AS 'First Name',"
                            + "pMI AS 'M.I.',"
                            + "pSex AS 'Sex',"
                            + "pStatus AS 'Status',"
                            + "pTelNo AS 'Contact No.',"
                            + "pDocID AS 'Doctor ID',"
                            + "pAddr AS 'St. No.',"
                            + "pStreet AS 'St. Name',"
                            + "pBarangay AS 'Barangay',"
                            + "pCity AS 'City',"
                            + " pProvince AS 'Province',"
                            + " pLNameKIN AS 'Last Name',"
                            + "pFNameKIN AS 'First Name',"
                            + "pMIKIN AS 'M.I.',"
                            + "pRelationKIN AS 'Relation',"
                            + "pTotalDue AS 'Total Due'"
                            + " FROM dbo.Patients");
```

First I run this line (pTotalDue didn't come up to jTable.)

And on my second attempt to display it I do this:

```
"SELECT pTotalDue AS 'Total Due' FROM dbo.Patients"
```

Now I tried this one, and I think something's really wrong about my codes. BTW this column has MONEY DATA TYPE

why does it didn't show to my `JTable`? could anyone tell me what is the problem with my codes?

(Problem in the answer that has given to me)
    public class QueryOnWorkerThread extends SwingWorker{
      private final JTable tableToUpdate;

```
  public QueryOnWorkerThread( JTable aTableToUpdate ) {
    tableToUpdate = aTableToUpdate;
  }

  @Override
  protected TableModel doInBackground() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:OJT_dsn";
    String user = "sa";
    String pass = "";
    Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection( url, user, pass );
    Statement state = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("");
    ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    Vector column_name = new Vector();
    Vector data_rows;

    //note the <= check iso the < check (as the count starts at index 1)
    for (int i=1; i<=columns;i++){
      column_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
    }
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(column_name);

    while(rs.next()){
      data_rows = new Vector();
      //note the <= check iso the < check (as the count starts at index 1)
      for (int j=1; j<=columns; j++){
        data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
      }
      dtm.addRow(data_rows);
    }
    return dtm;
  }


        `@Override <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I have a problem here it says : done() in javaapplication25.SearchPatient.QueryWorkerThread cannot override done() in javax.swing.SwingWorker overriden method does not throw java.lang.Exception , what does it mean sir?` 
  protected void done() throws Exception{
    //this method runs on the EDT, so it is safe to update our table here
    try {
      tableToUpdate.setModel( get() );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException( e );
    } catch ( ExecutionException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you have any field decimal in database table Patients

Comment: yes the pTotalDue that is MONEY DATA TYPE and contain decimals.

Comment: convert that to string

Comment: the last part am I right sir?

Comment: I did put .toString() to that str18 and same error occured.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27932/discussion-between-crystal-maiden-and-nidhishkrishnan)

Comment: String str18=""+acrs.getInt(18);      try this

Comment: cannot find symbols acrs

Comment: @CrystalMaiden - you overrode the method `done` from `SwingWorker`, but added an exception to the signature. Note that subclasses can throw fewer exceptions when overriding a method from a parent class, but they can never throw ***more***.

Comment: After all the answers you got below..Are you still facing problems with you code?

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
for (int i = dtm.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
dtm.removeRow(i);
}

Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
Statement state = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("Your SQL Query");

while(rs.next())
{
String str1=rs.getString(1);
String str2=rs.getString(2);
String str3=rs.getString(3);
String str4=rs.getString(4);
String str5=rs.getString(5);
:
:
:
dtm.addRow(new Object[]{str1,str2,str3,str4,str5});
}
```

Comment: sir i tried your codes, here's what Ive got :

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
 at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:505)
 at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
 at javax.swing.JTable$DoubleRenderer.setValue(JTable.java:5367)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(DefaultTableCellRenderer.java:257)
 at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5735)

Comment: kindly look at the edit, in the last part that's the code that I used before getting that tons of error.

Answer (score 6):

In you loops, your exit condition is

```
j<columns
```

this means thant the last column will never be recovered. try this insted:

```
for (int j=1; j<=columns; j++)
```

Comment: sir Joan, same result happen. I mean nothing happen still.... it didn't display the MONEY DATA TYPE

Comment: Have you changed the column_name population loop? It has the same condition.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that your last column does not appear is probably related to your loop statements, as already indicated by @Joan.

There are however more issues with this code. You should only update Swing components on the Event Dispatch Thread, and on that Thread you should not perform long running operations. In short, mixing SQL queries and updates of the `JTable` should not happen on the same thread. Consult the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) guide for more info.

Using a `SwingWorker` could solve this issue:

```
public class QueryOnWorkerThread extends SwingWorker<TableModel, Void>{
  private final JTable tableToUpdate;

  public QueryOnWorkerThread( JTable aTableToUpdate ) {
    tableToUpdate = aTableToUpdate;
  }

  @Override
  protected TableModel doInBackground() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:******";
    String user = "*****";
    String pass = "*****";
    Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection( url, user, pass );
    Statement state = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("");
    ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    Vector column_name = new Vector();
    Vector data_rows;

    //note the <= check iso the < check (as the count starts at index 1)
    for (int i=1; i<=columns;i++){
      column_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
    }
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(column_name);

    while(rs.next()){
      data_rows = new Vector();
      //note the <= check iso the < check (as the count starts at index 1)
      for (int j=1; j<=columns; j++){
        data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
      }
      dtm.addRow(data_rows);
    }
    return dtm;
  }

  @Override
  protected void done() {
    //this method runs on the EDT, so it is safe to update our table here
    try {
      tableToUpdate.setModel( get() );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException( e );
    } catch ( ExecutionException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
  }
}
```

The `SwingWorker` can be started by calling

```
QueryOnWorkerThread worker = new QueryOnWorkerThread( tblPatient );
worker.execute();
```

Note how I changed the loops in your code

Comment: sir @Robin kindly look at the edit at the end part, I can't post it as comment because it's too long, I indicated also what is the problem with the codes that you provide here.

Comment: @CrystalMaiden why have you added the `throws Exception`. That method may not throw an exception. You should catch them (as I did for the `InterruptedException` and the `ExecutionException`

Answer (score 4):

Try getting that column via `ResultSet.getBigDecimal()` rather than via `ResultSet.getString()`. Then put your retrieved `BigDecimal.toPlainString()` into your table cell.

*Example:*

```
data_rows.addElement(rs.getBigDecimal("pTotalDue").toPlainString());//Assuming your select returns a pTotalDue Column (e.g. SELECT pTotalDue,... FROM ...)
```

Comment: sir, there is a red line cannot find the symbol : method getPlainString(), why is that? and if I used Intellisense after ("pTotalDue") it appear only one thing and that is getClass()

Answer (score 3):

Try to Use an TableCellRenderer.

Implement the Renderer and render the Column with the Money Type in the form you wish.

Regards,
HL